# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, server

After I upload my website on server, I got that message .. I searched on Internet and I found on Wordpress community this [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/installation/) , I followed the installation steps, the error message gone, but I got white screen !

Comment: Have you checked that your wp-config.php file contains the correct details to connect to the database?

Comment: the problem with PHP version on Server, I solved it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the PHP version on server from 5.3 to 5.4 and it worked fine, because wordpress version needs at least PHP version 5.4 . [source](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your hosting server have installed mysql server, if that's not case and you are using paid hosting you can always contact your hosting provider for support.

Comment: Sorry but how can I check if mysql server installed or not ?, in the cPanel there is a section named 'Database', and I created a database user and database then uploaded my database ..

Comment: If you are on paid hosting than probabbly the mysql server is installed. If you are using own VPS or Dedicated server you can check it by opening SSH and run next command: **sudo service mysql status**

Comment: The Problem was with PHP version, I changed it from 5.3 to 5.4 and it worked fine !